# Converting Access calculated field to T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, migrate

I'm trying to manually migrate an access query which is actually an expression (calculated field in access.

The access expression in question is:

```
Balance2: (IIf(([OutstandingBalance]-nz([PartsStockForJobTotals]! 
[Expr1]))>0,([OutstandingBalance]-nz([PartsStockForJobTotals]![Expr1])),0))* 
[Part Assembly Link Table]![Qty]
```

So far I have managed to write the SQL code:

```
SELECT
IIF([Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] - 
ISNULL([PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1], 0) >0,
[Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] - 
ISNULL([PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1], 0), 0 *
[Part Assembly Link Table].[QTY]) AS Balance2,

FROM ((([PART LIBARY HEADER] 
INNER JOIN [Part Assembly Link Table] 
ON [PART LIBARY HEADER].PartID = [Part Assembly Link Table].PartIDParent) 
INNER JOIN [PART LIBARY HEADER] AS [PART LIBARY HEADER_1] 
ON [Part Assembly Link Table].PartIDChild = [PART LIBARY HEADER].PartID) 
INNER JOIN [Order Transactions Table] 
ON [PART LIBARY HEADER].[Part Number] = [Order Transactions Table].[Part 
Number]) 
LEFT JOIN PartsStockForJobTotals 
ON [Order Transactions Table].[Item Referance] = PartsStockForJobTotals. 
[Item Referance]
```

Now everything up until this point returns records. However I am trying to filter only records where '**Balance2**' is Greater than 0.

This is the WHERE clause that I use but it retrieves no rows:

```
WHERE 
IIF([Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] - 
ISNULL([PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1], 0) >0,
[Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] - 
ISNULL([PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1], 0), 0 *
[Part Assembly Link Table].[QTY]) > 0;
```

Obviously Aliases aren't allowed to be used in WHERE clauses so i just copied and pasted '**Balance2**' into the where statement and appended it with a **> 0**

Comment: @OwlsSleeping [`IIF()` is available in tsql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) although I would argue that `Case` is better in most cases merely because it's portable. `Iif()` seems reasonable in cases where one might be inclined to user a ternary operator like when `CASE` is just too verbose.

Comment: It is also possible to do IIF in T-SQL I believe. Is it more beneficial to use Case on this occasion? 
Edit: What @JNevill Said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this! Thanks for **@Jnevill** and **@Gordon Linoff** for the code simplifying but my WHERE clause was not working because I had an incorrect link between the tables. Access creates temporary tables when multiple instances are added to the query pallet. It appends the second instance with **_1** which in my case was **PART LIBARY HEADER_1**

Initially my Joins did not specify this connection:

```
PART LIBARY HEADER ----> PART ASSEMBLY LINK TABLE ----> PART LIBARY HEADER_1
```

But after re-doing the join's the where clause provided by **@Gordon Linoff** seemed to do the trick. The exact results are being returned as it is in Access.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would write this as:

```
     (CASE WHEN ott.[OutstandingBalance] < COALESCE(psfjt.[EXPR1], 0)
           THEN ott.[OutstandingBalance] - COALESCE(psfjt.[EXPR1], 0)
           ELSE 0 
      END) * palt.[Qty] AS Balance2
  . . .
FROM . . .
     [Order Transactions Table] ott . . .
     [PartsStockForJobTotals] psfjt . . .
     [Part Assembly Link Table] palt
```

Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Then the `WHERE` would be:

```
WHERE (ott.OutstandingBalance - COALESCE(psfjt.EXPR1, 0)) * palt.qty > 0
```

I don't think conditional logic is needed in the `WHERE`.

Comment: This is a better rewrite of the code but i am still retrieving 0 Rows when adding the where clause. it seems only 'Balance2' with value of 0 is being returned with the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

A quick rewrite of your rewrite to be more performant and portable:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] < [PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1] 
    THEN [Order Transactions Table].[OutstandingBalance] - ISNULL([PartsStockForJobTotals].[EXPR1], 0)
  ELSE 0 
  END AS Balance2
```

Switching here to use a CASE statement which is similar to `IIF()` but is more portable (will work in any RDBMS except for Access), where `IIF()` will only work on newer versions of SQL Server and Access (not Oracle, Postgres, DB2, MySQL, MariaDB, etc etc etc etc).

Also the math to subtract the two values and test for `>0` is expensive. Just test to see if one is greater than the other.

Lastly your `ELSE` condition here can just be written as `0` instead of `0 *
[Part Assembly Link Table].[QTY]` as anything times 0 is 0.

This should work just fine in you WHERE clause too (although I have no idea why your WHERE was failing in the first place, so there may be more to this).

Comment: Did you intend for: 
    End AND Balance2 ? Not AS?

Comment: I had a stray `AND` in there. Definitely fat fingered that one. Fixed now.

Comment: The WHERE is failing somewhere and I am not sure why. The logic seems foolproof and is also retrieving records when executed in Access. They are link tables both looking at the same place.

Comment: @JNevill You state "the math to subtract the two values and test for `>0` is expensive". Could you cite a source for the substantial overhead involved? Typical processor architectures perform comparisons by subtracting one value from the other and setting condition codes which are subsequently checked. The optimized code for `A - B > 0` and `A > B` is likely to be the same.

Comment: I don't have a source, but I worry that there is a lot between the CPU and the SQL. Would the RDBMS type-check the integer literal against the type outputted from the subtraction to insure that a potential implicit cast is needed before running out the condition (for instance). Ultimately I find the `<` easier to understand. All that being said, I like Gordon's answer better as I think it solves an issue that OP hasn't discovered yet in their logic.

Comment: I have adjusted my code to match Gordon's suggestion and this did not resolve the actual problem. While the code may look cleaner now, it still brings the same result of having nothing returned with the WHERE clause Gordon suggested.

Comment: What happens when you remove the WHERE condition. Does the new column using the same logic show records where that WHERE condition would return `TRUE`. It doesn't sound like it does.